# Does Windows recycle/reuse Registered Clipboard Format ids

Tags: windows, clipboard

### Question

Windows has a RegisterClipboardFormat function that returns an id >0xC000 <0xFFFF given a name for that format.

If the format is already registered it will return the same id it returned last time.

Since there are only 4k ids available, if many applications were to request unique formats they might eventually need to re-use formats. Does windows ever free up a format ID for re-use?

### Why I care

I would like to test if a format is already registered. Unfortunately Windows doesn't provide a function for that (as least as far as I've found). If windows never recycles the ids, I can just keep a list of the formats already registered and not have to search all 4K ids every time I need to test.

### Update

So far I've just examined all of the formats on one computer.
[GetClipboardFormatName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040(v=vs.85).aspx) returned 0 with errorcode 0x06 for formats:

- 0xC000
- 0xC100
- 0xC200
- 0xC300
- 0xC3AA
- 0xC3AE-0xFFFF

So my initial guess is that all multiples of 0x100 are reserved internally and there is indeed recycling of some sort as otherwise 0cC3AA would not be free. Additional testing to come.

Comment: I feel like you might be able to test this on your own.  Just try making over 4k clipboard format IDs and keep track of which values have been returned.  If you ever get an ID you've seen before, you'll know your answer.  If it start to return failures after 4k, you've also got your answer.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see if it gets slower as you get further along.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I would assume that if windows did recycle the ids it would at least wait till the application that registered it was closed, but that might just be optimistic. If I don't get a thorough answer I'll set up a test with a few instances of a program that registers 1K unique formats.

Comment: Can you clarify the "Context" paragraph at the end of the question?  Windows doesn't give you a way to test if a particular format has been registered.  What do you mean that you'd have to search 4000 IDs?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Windows does give you [GetClipboardFormatName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040(v=vs.85).aspx) though. Which lets you test IDs and get their formats, so you can search for a particular format but calling this on every registerable ID. If windows doesn't recycle them, then I'd only ever have to call it once for each registered ID and could keep the result (in a O(log n) tree) similarly if it assigns IDs incrementally I could just test the IDs defined since last test +1. (also it's 4,096 IDs, but that's not really relevant)

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of GetClipboardFormatName.  Windows won't recycle format IDs, because it has no way to know if an application is still using one.  If an application tries to register a new clipboard format when Windows is out of IDs, then the registration would fail.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy If you have documentation and/or evidence, please post it as an answer, and I'll accept it. It sounds reasonable. However, and this is unlikely, but I suppose it could be possible for windows to keep a list of PIDs of all running programs that registered a format, and then if it has run out of IDs just start writing over the formats that don't have any PIDs left on them. I haven't found any documentation on this behavior, so I was trying to not eliminate any feasible possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

After experimenting using [GetClipboardFormatName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040(v=vs.85).aspx) I've discovered the windows 7 will Register new formats in the first valid entry*. Additionally, formats sometimes** become unregistered. Those unregistered handle ID's then become valid entries for future formats.

*it seems that multiples of 0x100 are never registered

**I haven't been able to determine the conditions for when formats become unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

I think they reset on reboot.  i.e. Rich Text Format will give you one answer today, keep using that value until you reboot, and then you'll get a different number.  I haven't tested this lately, but I'm pretty sure I did once in the past, but it may have been 20 years ago!